# Finding the sorted list of prime factors of a number

Tags: python

What is wrong with my code?

```
def exercise_2(n): 
primfac = []
d = 2
while d*d <= n:
    if (n%d) == 0:
        primfac.append(d)
        n //= d
    d += 1
       
if n > 1:
    primfac.append(n)
    
return primfac
```

I'm trying to get the prime factors of a number, and the output it gives is `[2,5,10]`. The output I want is `[2,5]`

Also, this is the assertion error I'm getting when `n = 100`

```
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [4], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 ans = exercise_2(100)
----> 2 assert ans==[2,5]
      4 ans = exercise_2(3674)
      5 assert ans==[2,11,167]

AssertionError:
```

Answer (score -1):

**For your example:**

After first loop iteration, n = 50 (100/2) and i = 3

After second loop iteration, n = 50 and i = 4

After third loop iteration, n = 50 and i = 5

After fourth loop iteration, n = 10 (50/5) and i = 6

Now, 6*6 < 10, hence the while loop terminates.

You then append n (which is 10) to your prime factor list.

Hope this helps see where your code is going wrong!